# How can I easily test connectivity to external sources with WinHTTP?

Tags: windows, troubleshooting, winhttp

I've got an server application that uses Winhttp to fetch information from an external source.  Occasionally, I'll need to troubleshoot connectivity issues and I'd like an easy way to test connections through winHTTP (on the off-chance that there's something that is specifically impeding winHTTP and not other unrelated connectivity commands like telnet).

Does IE use WinHTTP? If not, are there any tools (preferably already integrated into Windows) that I can use? Occasionally I'll use IE but I'm not sure if that's quite the same.

Answer (score 1):

There is a website located on [this](http://www.henrycipolla.com/blog/2010/10/let-me-dump-your-post-free-http-post-test-server/) blog that was developed to test WinHTTP.  The link directly to the site is [here](http://www.posttestserver.com/).

Comment: Thanks but I don't think that's quite what I'm looking for.  I specifically want to test through the WinHTTP component/service running on a local system.